# How to extract numbers from an array involved also from strings also from numbers?

Tags: r

```
x<-c("Hello","World",4,"Shalom",3,"olam")
```

How to extract numbers from an array involved also from strings also from numbers in R?

Comment: The question is difficult to parse as is, but I think that's what you want: `stringr::str_subset(c("Hello","World",4,"Shalom",3,"olam"), "\\d")`

Comment: I want to run on the array and print only the numbers